# If a closed set in projective space is stabilized by an automorphism, so are its components

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a closed set in $\mathbb{P}^n$, and let $\phi$ be an automorphism of varieties $\mathbb{P}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$.  If $\phi$ stabilizes $X$, does it follow that $\phi$ stabilizes the irreducible components of $X$?  This is not true in the affine case. For example, $\phi: \mathbb{A}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1$, $\phi(x) = -x$ is an isomorphism of varieties, and $\{1,-1\}$ is a $\phi$-stable closed set in $\mathbb{A}^1$ whose irreducible components $\{1\}$ and $\{-1\}$ are not fixed.

In projective space, similar counterexamples are obviously not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to your claim similar examples **are** possible in projective space:
Just take the automorphism $\phi:\mathbb P^1\to \mathbb P^1:[x,y]\mapsto [x,-y]$ which leaves globally invariant the subvariety $X\subset \mathbb P^1$ given by $x^2-y^2=0$ but permutes its irreducible components, namely the one-point sets  $\{[1,1]\}$ and $\{[1,-1]\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X = \{[1:0:0], [0: 1:0], [0:0:1]\} \subset \mathbb{P}^2$. It is known that the automorphism group of $\mathbb{P}^n$ is $GL_n(k)$ modulo action of scalars. Take $\phi$ to be the matrix that permutes the above three points cyclically. None of the irreducible components (individual points) are fixed.